# IOS device kid changed screen time passcode and claims he did not , help me catch him

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app, hacking

My son has a iphone xs.   we set a screen time passcode becasue he kept turning off his phone location.  and then next when i loooked at the phone, the same restrictions were showing locked. i changed the "share my location" to "always" or "allow."  It's now changed to "never" or is greyed out.. and my son appears to have found out the screen time passcode and changed it.  I can no longer login into the screentime passcode that i set. i wrote down. its now at so many attempts i have to wait over an hour before i try again the alert says. i have 87 attempts. it was changed.

I found an app that would locate the last password set and this app cannot even find it.  the phone location is still sharring on my phone but the location option on his phone is set to never share.

I also noticed there was in the text messaging section 3 ... that i have never seen. they told me that when there phone updated, this came with it.

The shortcut app on the phone i noticed allows for an option to script and things like that.  is this a standard new update of the app or was this something put onn the phone?

Either way, i have acess to the phone but i cant do anything and i dont no what passcode was set in place.

How can I regain control over this device?

Comment: Instead of worrying over these details, consider this approach: Take the phone away from your child. Also perhaps consider the "answer" that's best for you and your son may not be a technical  answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing. Offer your son a non-threatening chance to help fix the passcode. Why fight someone when you can convince them you will win and gain their acceptance and cooperation after they break the rules?

That being said, just wipe the device if you’re out of patience. Connect to iTunes on windows, Mac. Erase the device and start over.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

As long as you are clear where the boundaries lie and if the device is for your conveneNiece or their convenience you can plan to lock it down again or get more skill at countering your son that may have more time to learn how to foil your boundaries.